# How to overlay/merge two types of charts in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am looking to merge bar chart and line chart in the same responsive container in recharts, in a way that they overlay each other. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need [Composed Chart](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ComposedChart) from their API and you can decide what chart can overlay another by placing it higher or lower in your code.